# jQuery find / is(':visible') problem

Tags: jquery, find, hide, show, visible

Please see the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wQpTu/1/

For some reason, it always returns false on the .is(':visible') whether or not it is visible.

Any reason why? Anything I should be doing differently?

Comment: wrong selector :) it's an id: span#spanselect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use:

```
var visibleElement = $('#holder').find("span#spanselect").is(":visible");
```

`spanselect` is an `id`, not a `class`.

`$("#holder span#spanselect")` would work just the same, by the way. For the record, you can changed `is(":visible")` to `length` ans saw it was equal to `0`, and easily see the selector fails.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/wQpTu/5/

Comment: Since you're using an id, there is no reason not to just use $("#spanselect") to begin with though.

Comment: @Dennis - That's a very good point, though there are edge cases - for example, maybe you want the selector to fail if `#spanselect` isn't inside `#holder` (if it moves) - but that's far fetched `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using "." instead of "#". [This](http://jsfiddle.net/wQpTu/6/) will work:

```
var visibleElement = $('#holder').find("span.spanselect").is(":visible");
```